# Import a 3d scene into babylonJS

Tags: 3d, blender

So I read today about [babylonJS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/06/27/babylon-js-a-complete-javascript-framework-for-building-3d-games-with-html-5-and-webgl.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) and I was blown away by it. I'm trying to figure out how to load an entire 3d scene into babylon. I've managed to export a 3d model of spider man and have the .babylon file but then what? In the document it only states 
"Importing scene from 3D assets
Babylon.js can load scenes from a file format called .babylon. This file format is based on JSON and contains all required data to create a complete scene."

Any ideas on how to achieve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have a `.babylon` file, you can call the [SceneLoader.Load](https://doc.babylonjs.com/classes/3.1/sceneloader#static-load-rooturl-scenefilename-engine-onsuccess-onprogress-onerror-pluginextension-rarr-nullable-lt-isceneloaderplugin-gt-) function:

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load("", "scene.babylon", engine, function (newScene) {

});
```

the `Load` function takes the following parameters:

- scene folder (can be empty to use the same folder as your page)
- scene file name
- a reference to the engine
- a callback to give you the loaded scene (in my case, I use this callback to attach the
  camera to the canvas and to launch my render loop)
- a callback for progress report

More details here:
https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=313

Comment: What about adding only one model to an already loaded scene? Looks like `BABYLON.SceneLoader.ImportMeshes`. These are loading from a remote server, ie making http request. [How about loading them from local file system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124526/loading-local-files-into-a-babylonjs-scene-directly)