# Babylon.js Scene is not loading

Tags: javascript, 3d, blender, babylonjs

I am trying to load `.babylon` file. But it doesn't load any thing, the page is blank.

I was using the following links:

1. [Import a 3d scene into babylonJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354398/import-a-3d-scene-into-babylonjs)
2. [How to load Babylon file produced with blender](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/06/28/babylon-js-how-to-load-a-babylon-file-produced-with-blender.aspx)

The sample files provided by the second link didn't work on my machine. Then I found that they need to be hosted on a server. After uploading the files on **dropbox.com** they started working but my file is still not working.

The code on the link:

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load("", "scene.babylon", engine, function (newScene) {
```

I just changed it to:

```
BABYLON.SceneLoader.Load("", "myscene.babylon", engine, function (newScene) {
```

The error in the browser's `console` is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined                 babylon.js:1
BABYLON.Vector3.FromArray                                                 babylon.js:1
(anonymous function)                                                      babylon.js:11
request.onreadystatechange                                                babylon.js:1
```

**Additional Information:**

`myscene.babylon` is exported from `blender` using `Babylon Exporter` available on **GitHub** official link.

It only contains a `cube` and a `plane`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also added the step to define MIME type on your webserver to this article (Thanks to David Rousset):
[How to load a .babylon file](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/06/28/babylon-js-how-to-load-a-babylon-file-produced-with-blender.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Does your file work in our online sandbox: http://www.babylonjs.com/sandbox ?

You just have to drag'n'drop your .babylon file into the sandbox. If it works, this means you have a webserver configuration issue.

Bye,

David

Comment: Yes it works in the sandbox. What should I do to work with my server?

Comment: You probably forgot to add the proper mime type declaration for .babylon files on your webserver. You'll find the exact step in my tutorial here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davrous/archive/2013/11/19/using-webgl-to-create-games-for-the-windows-store.aspx

Comment: When I upload your files to dropbox.com they work, but my files give error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`, you said I need to add `MIME types`, so why not your files need `MIME types` to be added their?