# Issue trying to use a .babylon file on html

Tags: 3dsmax, babylonjs

I'm trying to import a 3D scene from 3ds max to a html page, this is where I came up:

1) I imported a obj scene to 3ds max.
2) I exported the scene to a .babylon file (with one of the github exporters).
3) I opened the file in the sandbox of babylonjs.com.
4) I saved the html page.
5) I made the changes ("Loading your .babylon inside your page / app") listed in:http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/06/28/babylon-js-how-to-load-a-babylon-file-produced-with-blender.aspx?CommentPosted=true&PageIndex=3#comments.
and
[Import a 3d scene into babylonJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17354398/import-a-3d-scene-into-babylonjs/17476415#17476415)

But when I want to open through my web server (xampp) just a blank screen appears, and if I do not make changes of the point 5 gets stuck in "loading" message.

What am I doing wrong?
Sorry if my question is very obvious, I'm new to babylonjs.

Here some images:
https://mega.co.nz/#!6VUDSIqL!ARNCGHJPutaChKWlWy0vtUi74anr3LtsiN2Pgd3niG8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your apache server is not serving .babylon mimes types. If you are looking at your network tab in f12 tools you will see that .babylon file request returns a 403

Comment: Thanks David, it worked but the server return me 404 texture-images that I put it in the folder where the html was. One last question: how can I join 2 or more babylon files into one html? this is because I cannot export from 3dsMax pieces greater than 65565 vertices.

Comment: The latest v2.0 alpha now support 32bits indices but you can also useSceneLoader.Append to merge scenes:)